# Trouble installing Redmine on CentOS 6.2 - undefined method db for main:object

Tags: centos, ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I am trying to install RedMine on CentOS 6.2 but I am running into difficulties when I try to access the site. [Using this guide](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_install_Redmine_on_CentOS_Detailed), I have configured the following in `environment.rb`:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Make sure there's no plugin in vendor/plugin before starting
vendor_plugins_dir = File.join(Rails.root, "vendor", "plugins")
if Dir.glob(File.join(vendor_plugins_dir, "*")).any?
  $stderr.puts "Plugins in vendor/plugins (#{vendor_plugins_dir}) are no longer allowed. " +
    "Please, put your Redmine plugins in the `plugins` directory at the root of your " +
    "Redmine directory (#{File.join(Rails.root, "plugins")})"
  exit 1
end

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'

#RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake generate_session_store
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate

# Initialize the rails application
RedmineApp::Application.initialize!
```

Unfortunately, I keep running into the following error:

`undefined method 'db' for main:Object`

I get the same problem when I try to run the command manually:

```
[root@nag0 config]# rake db:migrate --trace
(in /var/www/html/redmine-2.2.2)
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
undefined method `db' for main:Object
/var/www/html/redmine-2.2.2/config/environment.rb:16
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `initialize_tasks'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `call'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `execute'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `each'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `execute'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:166:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:185:in `each'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:185:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:152:in `invoke'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `top_level'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `top_level'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `run'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

I have configured the `database.yml` file with my MySQL database login/password.

Given that I am new to Ruby in general, I am sure that I am doing something wrong, but unfortunately I do not know enough about how Ruby works to troubleshoot much further.

Any suggestions are always appreciated.

Comment: Did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: Yep, I did. `Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you confirm that you've configured `config/database.yml` rather than `config/db.yml`?  If not, you've named your database configuration file incorrectly.

You've also misread the guide.  Under the section *Generate the session store*, commands to execute are listed - not additions to `environment.rb`.

Remove the lines

```
#RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake generate_session_store
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

from your `environment.rb` and proceed with the guide by executing the commands in the *Generate the session store* at the command line instead.

Comment: I mis-typed, the `database.yml` file was named correctly. But, after removing those lines and running `update_rubygems`, those commands worked!